# Translate SoapUi Project to Equivalent DotNet WCF Client Code/Configuration

Tags: c#, wcf, soapui, x509

I have been given a "working" SoapUi 4.0.1 project that accesses an existing 3rd party service. The project has two xml requests that I can run to see, in SoapUi , a "found" and a "not found" response.

Along with the project is a wsdl file a couple of certificate files (for message security) and a bunch of xml schemas.

I've been told to implement a c# client that uses the service based on the "documentation" provided by the above.

I'm not experienced in the intricacies of WCF configuration nor SoapUi. There, at least, there seems to be a mismatch between the terminology SoapUi uses and that I see in the WCF configuration tool.

I'm looking for advice, hints, pointers on duplicating the SoapUi calls in my .NET code, perhaps a terminology mapping between the two tools would be a good start.

Comment: If you have the URL to the service, you can use svcutil to generate a proxy you can use in the client. See [ServiceModel Metadata Utility Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx).  You can also use it just with the supplied WSDL.

Comment: I've created a proxy using the wsdl file. It may have issues, in that instead of string for some types it shows @string. My larger problem is in the configuration of the access to the service. For example where/how do I attach and map the SoapUi parameters for outgoing and incoming security that use cccc.jks and the signature file that is called yyyy.pfx

Comment: Your WCF client typically uses Windows Certificate Store for certificates. Import the certificates in your Windows Certificate Store and configure your client to use them. You do this by adding a clientCredentials endpoint behavior with the clientCertificate pointed out. Also you will need to configure the binding to use certificates. Use the Microsoft Service Configuration Editor tool to edit the configuration file.

Comment: please publish how the working SOAP that soapUI generated looks like

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a service proxy using the right-click "Add Service Reference" in Visual Studio or by running the SVCUTIL.EXE tool from a VS command-line. This will provide you with both a basic configuration file as well as a client implementation. All you need to do this is the actual metadata files (WSDL+XSD) or a URL to a hosted version of it.

It is not clear weather the SoapUI project you have makes client requests to the actual service or if it uses the built-in MockService feature where SoapUI hosts a 'fake' service instance. Either way the MockService feature can be your best friend doing WCF development.

If you are using the SoapUI MockService feature and do not have the original WSDL or access to it you can then use the metadata exposed by the MockService. One way of finding the link to the WSDL is by clicking the link button:

[image]

Copy the URL you get from there and generate the proxy from a Visual Studio command-prompt:

```
svcutil.exe http://localhost:8088/mockKramerServiceSoap?WSDL
```

SoapUI has one really great feature when trying to replicate SOAP calls in WCF. You can examine requests coming into the MockService from the .NET proxy and compare them with the calls made from SoapUI.

[image]

Hopefully this helped you getting started.

Comment: It makes calls to the actual service.

Comment: Ok, thats really good as you can test it all the way. I would anyway recommend that you during your development phase add a MockService in SoapUI (right click - Generate MockService) as this gives you (faked) control over the service-side. You can see exactly how the request your WCF client sends looks. This is especially true dealing with types that can cause deserialization errors such as dates etc.